# Google play console License testing not working

Tags: google-play-console

I try to add test subscription for Google Play and I'm not able to add License testers to my account:

[image]

No License testers are displayed! If I add a new license tester in the input field and click "Save changes" nothing changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After entering email id in "Add license testers" field you need to press enter to update the testers list then press save changes and choose the "License response" as LICENSED to test subscription.

Comment: Oh, that easy. I can't believe how long that stopped me from progressing...

Comment: Yeah, it happens sometimes and it's fine.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. It took me an embarrassingly long time to realize that you have to press enter to submit the list.

Comment: What a terrible UI. Thanks for this answer though--I was stuck thinking I lacked the proper permissions.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for weeks now

Comment: I'm glad I only stuck for 10 mins, but this needs to be more accessible and save developer time.

Key words: `Press Enter`